# Make a mostly pass through wrapper component in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I want to make a wrapper method that allows me to extend any disable-able component to support disabled message.

so that:

```
<MyWrappedComponent disabled={'requires admins approval'} />
```

would render

```
<Tooltip>
    reqires admins approval 
    <MyComponent disabled={true}/>
</Tooltip>
```

Here is what I have:

```
const withDisabledMessage = <T extends { disabled?: boolean }>(InnerComponent: FunctionComponent<T>) => {
    return forwardRef((
        wrapperProps: Omit<T, 'disabled'> & { disabled: boolean | string | undefined },
        ref: ForwardedRef<T>,
    ) => {

        const {
            disabled, ...restProps
        } = wrapperProps;

        const newProps = {
            ...restProps, disabled: !!wrapperProps.disabled,
        };
        if (typeof ((wrapperProps as { disabled: boolean | string | undefined }).disabled) === 'string') {
            return <div>
                <span>Disabled text: { wrapperProps.disabled }</span>
                <InnerComponent { ...newProps } ref={ ref }/>
            </div>;
        } else {
            return <InnerComponent { ...newProps } ref={ ref }/>;
        }
    });
};
```

This works but I'm getting an error:

> TS2322: Type 'Omit<Omit<T, "disabled"> & { disabled: string | boolean; }, "disabled"> & { ref: ForwardedRef; disabled: boolean; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & T'.   Type 'Omit<Omit<T, "disabled"> & { disabled: string | boolean; }, "disabled"> & { ref: ForwardedRef; disabled: boolean; }' is not assignable to type 'T'.     'Omit<Omit<T, "disabled"> & { disabled: string | boolean; }, "disabled"> & { ref: ForwardedRef; disabled: boolean; }' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint '{ disabled?: boolean; }'.

I think I understand where the error is coming from (`T` can be constrained to be more strict, for example T could be `{ disabled: true }`) - I just don't know how to solve this.

I can "fix" it by casting:`...(newProps as T)` instead of just `...newProps`.

Is there a way to build this without overriding `newProps` type?